# Select data from MySQL table conditional on the contents of the column schema comment in C#

Tags: c#, mysql

I have a function that returns a dictionary object with data from a table.  As the fields change a lot, I made it build the dictionary fields dynamically:

```
Dictionary<string, string> getData(string indexvalue) {
  Dictionary<string, string> ret = new Dictionary<string, string>();
  using (MySqlConnection DB = getConnection()) {
    using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM table WHERE indexfield = ?v", DB)) {
      DB.Open();
      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?v", indexvalue);
      using (MySqlDataReader RS = cmd.ExecuteReader()) {
        DataTable schemaTable = RS.GetSchemaTable();
        if (!RS.HasRows) return ret;
        while (RS.Read()) {
          foreach (DataRow fld in schemaTable.Rows) {
            ret.Add(fld["ColumnName"].ToString(), RS[fld["ColumnName"].ToString()].ToString());
          }
        }
      }
      DB.Close();
    }
  }
  return ret;
}
```

I want to be able to have it skip a column if the table schema has "skip" in the column's comments.  I can easily do it by running another SQL query as it processes the columns, but I'd rather find a way to do it without another query.  Is that possible?

Comment: Using the DataTable the way you do seems a little odd. If I'm not mistaken, you could simply `schemaTable.Load(RS)` and create a nested loop over a filtered set (`schemaTable.Columns.Where(c => !c.Caption.Contains("skip"))`) of `Column`s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My comment did not take into account that `DataTable.Columns` as a `DataColumnCollection` does not support Linq directly - however there is an easy workaround `Cast`ing to the desired type:

```
var nonskipcolumns = from c in schemaTable.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>() 
                     where !c.Caption.Contains("skip") 
                     select c.ColumnName;

foreach (var row in schemaTable.Rows.Cast<DataRow>())
{
    foreach (var col in nonskipcolumns)
    {
        ret.Add(col, (string)row[col]);
    }
}
```